# Get Members of Band

Tags: freebase, mql

If I look at the Freebase page for the band '311', I see Chad Sexton listed.

http://www.freebase.com/view/en/311

I am trying to query for the members of a band :

```
{
            "name"  : "311",
            "/music/artist/album" : [{"name":null, "id":null, "optional": true}],
            "type|=" : ["/music/artist","/music/musical_group"],
            "/award/award_winner/awards_won" : ["award":null, "optional" => true],
            "/award/award_nominated_work/award_nominations" : ["award":null, "optional" => true],
            "/music/artist/supporting_artists":[{}]
}
```

I thought supporting_artists would return the band member names, but the array is always empty.

But if I query for all properties related to Chad Sexton, I don't see 311 mentioned.  But he is listed as member on the Freebase web info page (which is correct).

```
{
  "*":    null,
  "name": "Chad Sexton",
  "type": "/music/artist"
}
```

How can I grab the band member names along with the band info?

Comment: Have you tried asking this question on the freebase website? It seems like a rather specific question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the [edit page for 311](http://www.freebase.com/edit/topic/en/311), you'll see that the supporting artists property is empty. The members of the band are listed further down the page under the [Musical Group type](http://www.freebase.com/type/schema/music/artist?domain=/music).

You can view the members of the band in your query by changing it to look like this:

```
{
  "name":          "311",
  "/music/artist/album": [{
    "name":     null,
    "id":       null,
    "optional": true
  }],
  "type|=": [
    "/music/artist",
    "/music/musical_group"
  ],
  "/award/award_winner/awards_won": [{
    "award":    null,
    "optional": true
  }],
  "/award/award_nominated_work/award_nominations": [{
    "award":    null,
    "optional": true
  }],
  "/music/musical_group/member": [{
    "member" : {}
  }]
}​
```

The reason why you have to query for member inside of /music/musical_group/member is because [Musical Group Membership](http://www.freebase.com/type/schema/music/group_membership) is a [Compound Value Type](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/CVT). It makes the query a little more complicated but its necessary in order to properly model the complex relationships of a band which may have many different members joining, leaving and switching roles throughout the life of the band.